# How to use QThread correctly in pyqt with moveToThread()?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, nonblocking, qthread

i read this article [How To Really, Truly Use QThreads; The Full Explanation](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/), it says instead of  subclass qthread, and reimplement run(), one should  use moveToThread to push a QObject onto QThread instance using moveToThread(QThread*)

here is the c++ example, but i don't know how to convert it to python code.

```cpp
class Worker : public QObject
 {
     Q_OBJECT
     QThread workerThread;

 public slots:
     void doWork(const QString &parameter) {
         // ...
         emit resultReady(result);
     }

 signals:
     void resultReady(const QString &result);
 };

 class Controller : public QObject
 {
     Q_OBJECT
     QThread workerThread;
 public:
     Controller() {
         Worker *worker = new Worker;
         worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
         connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
         connect(this, SIGNAL(operate(QString)), worker, SLOT(doWork(QString)));
         connect(worker, SIGNAL(resultReady(QString)), this, SLOT(handleResults(QString)));
         workerThread.start();
     }
     ~Controller() {
         workerThread.quit();
         workerThread.wait();
     }
 public slots:
     void handleResults(const QString &);
 signals:
     void operate(const QString &);
 };



QThread* thread = new QThread;
Worker* worker = new Worker();
worker->moveToThread(thread);
connect(worker, SIGNAL(error(QString)), this, SLOT(errorString(QString)));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(process()));
connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
thread->start();
```

i've been using this method to generate a qthread , but as you can see, it's using the not recommended way. how can i re-write it to use the preferred method ?

```py
class GenericThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        # super(GenericThread, self).__init__()

        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self, *args):
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
```

edit: two years later ...
I tried qris' code, it works and in different thread

```py
import sys
import time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
import threading


def logthread(caller):
    print('%-25s: %s, %s,' % (caller, threading.current_thread().name,
                              threading.current_thread().ident))


class MyApp(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('using threads')

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.testButton = QtGui.QPushButton("QThread")
        self.testButton.released.connect(self.test)
        self.listwidget = QtGui.QListWidget(self)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.testButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.listwidget)

        self.threadPool = []
        logthread('mainwin.__init__')

    def add(self, text):
        """ Add item to list widget """
        logthread('mainwin.add')
        self.listwidget.addItem(text)
        self.listwidget.sortItems()

    def addBatch(self, text="test", iters=6, delay=0.3):
        """ Add several items to list widget """
        logthread('mainwin.addBatch')
        for i in range(iters):
            time.sleep(delay)  # artificial time delay
            self.add(text+" "+str(i))

    def test(self):
        my_thread = QtCore.QThread()
        my_thread.start()

        # This causes my_worker.run() to eventually execute in my_thread:
        my_worker = GenericWorker(self.addBatch)
        my_worker.moveToThread(my_thread)
        my_worker.start.emit("hello")
        # my_worker.finished.connect(self.xxx)

        self.threadPool.append(my_thread)
        self.my_worker = my_worker


class GenericWorker(QtCore.QObject):

    start = pyqtSignal(str)
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GenericWorker, self).__init__()
        logthread('GenericWorker.__init__')
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.start.connect(self.run)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logthread('GenericWorker.run')
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        self.finished.emit()


# run
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
test = MyApp()
test.show()
app.exec_()
```

the ouput is:

```
mainwin.__init__         : MainThread, 140221684574016,
GenericWorker.__init__   : MainThread, 140221684574016,
GenericWorker.run        : Dummy-1, 140221265458944,
mainwin.addBatch         : Dummy-1, 140221265458944,
mainwin.add              : Dummy-1, 140221265458944,
mainwin.add              : Dummy-1, 140221265458944,
mainwin.add              : Dummy-1, 140221265458944,
mainwin.add              : Dummy-1, 140221265458944,
mainwin.add              : Dummy-1, 140221265458944,
mainwin.add              : Dummy-1, 140221265458944,
```

Comment: I'm surprised that this question has been unanswered/uncommented for so long. The [docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#moveToThread) clearly state that using `moveToThread(thread)` is the preffered way, but yet all example code I've been able to find subclasses `QThread.run()` and put work there. It would be great if we could see an example or a use pattern.

Comment: Here is an article that helped a lot when implementing my first thread: https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation . As you said it not a recommended practice to subclass QThread even if there are loads of tutorials doing that.

Comment: Is the final sample in the question correct? mainwin.add is where the code adds the item to the listwidget, but clearly from the printed output, we can see tat mainwin.add is executed in the thread?!?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The default run() implementation in QThread runs an event loop for you, the equivalent of:

```
class GenericThread(QThread):
    def run(self, *args):
        self.exec_()
```

The important thing about an event loop is that it allows objects **owned by** the thread to receive events on their slots, which will be executed **in that thread**. Those objects are just QObjects, not QThreads.

Important note: the QThread object **is not owned by its own thread** [[docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details)]:

> It is important to remember that a QThread instance lives in the old thread that instantiated it, not in the new thread that calls run(). This means that all of QThread's queued slots and invoked methods will execute in the old thread [e.g. the main thread].

So you should be able to do this:

```
class GenericWorker(QObject):
    def __init__(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GenericWorker, self).__init__()

        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.start.connect(self.run)

    start = pyqtSignal(str)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self, some_string_arg):
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

my_thread = QThread()
my_thread.start()

# This causes my_worker.run() to eventually execute in my_thread:
my_worker = GenericWorker(...)
my_worker.moveToThread(my_thread)
my_worker.start.emit("hello")
```

Also, think carefully about what happens with the result of `self.function`, which is currently discarded. You could declare another signal on `GenericWorker`, which receives the result, and have the `run()` method emit that signal when it's done, passing the result to it.

> Once you get the hang of it and realize you don't and shouldn't subclass QThread, life becomes a lot more straightforward and easier. Simply put, never do work in QThread. You should almost never need to override run. For most use cases, setting up proper associations with a QObject to a QThread and using QT's signals/slots creates an extremely powerful way to do multithreaded programming. Just be careful not to let the QObjects you've pushed to your worker threads hang around...

http://ilearnstuff.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/qthread-best-practices-when-qthread.html

Comment: Interestingly, the @pyqtSlot decorator for the run method is absolutely crucial here; when leaving it out (which is 'legal' in PyQt) will in this case lead to seemingly serial execution. Tested with python 2.7.3.

Comment: Important note: make sure `my_thread` and `my_worker` are stored if you create them in a method, otherwise the garbage collector will trash them and the worker won't run

Comment: Make sure you **do not assign a parent** to your worker QObject, not even the QThread. Otherwise the worker will run on the parent's thread, which usually is the main thread. You can check which thread is doing the work by using `threading.get_ident()` both in the main thread and inside the worker function.

Comment: This is the correct answer. But the decorator must be fixed for this to work: `@pyqtSlot()`. Without the parentheses this gives `TypeError: bytes or ASCII string expected not 'function'` in Python 3.9. For anyone using this code in a class: Make sure to store `my_thread` and `my_worker`, otherwise they WILL get garbage collected. I also confirm that *without* the decorator, the worker WILL execute in the main thread, which defies the whole purpose of this.

Answer (score 5):

I was attempting to use qris's example in my application, but kept having my code run in the my main thread!  It is the way the *signal* that he declared to call run!

Basically, when you connect it in the constructor of the object, the connection will exist between two objects **in the main thread - because the QObject's properties belong to the thread that created them**.  When you move the QObject to your new thread, **the connection doesn't move with you**.  Take away the line that connects your signal to the run function, and connect it **after you move the worker to its new thread!**

The relevant change from qris's answer:

```
class GenericWorker(QObject):
    def __init__(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GenericWorker, self).__init__()

        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    start = pyqtSignal(str)

    @pyqtSlot
    def run(self, some_string_arg):
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

my_thread = QThread()
my_thread.start()

# This causes my_worker.run() to eventually execute in my_thread:
my_worker = GenericWorker(...)
my_worker.moveToThread(my_thread)
my_worker.start.connect(my_worker.run) #  <---- Like this instead 
my_worker.start.emit("hello")
```

Comment: I tried @qris example code, it works, how can I tell they still in the same tread ? I updated my question with edits

Answer (score 4):

I've tried both @qris and @MatthewRunchey approaches.

*With* the `@pyqtSlot` decorator Qt checks the "location" of the worker instance when the signal is emitted: even if the connection was made before `moveToThread` emitting the signal after `moveToThread` executes the slot in the worker thread.

*Without* the `@pyqtSlot` decorator Qt freezes the "location" of the worker instance the moment when the connection was made: if it was before `moveToThread`, it is bound to the main thread, and the slot code keeps being executed in the main thread even if the signal is emitted after `moveToThread` call.

Connections made *after* `moveToThread` bind the slot to be executed the worker thread in both cases.

Code:

```
import threading
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QObject, QRunnable, QThread,
                          QThreadPool, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot)

class Worker(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
#        self.call_f1.connect(self.f1)
#        self.call_f2.connect(self.f2)

    call_f1 = pyqtSignal()
    call_f2 = pyqtSignal()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def f1(self):
        print('f1', threading.get_ident())
    
    @pyqtSlot()
    def f2(self):
        print('f2', threading.get_ident())

app = QCoreApplication([])
print('main', threading.get_ident())
my_thread = QThread()
my_thread.start()

my_worker = Worker()
my_worker.call_f1.connect(my_worker.f1)
my_worker.call_f1.emit()
my_worker.moveToThread(my_thread)
my_worker.call_f2.connect(my_worker.f2)
my_worker.call_f1.emit()
my_worker.call_f2.emit()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

With decorator:

```
main 18708
f1 18708
f1 20156
f2 20156
```

Without decorator:

```
main 5520
f1 5520
f1 5520
f2 11472
```

PS Connecting in the worker `__init__` method is obviously equivalent to connecting before `moveToThread` in the main thread.

(tested under PyQt5, win64).

Comment: 2. It is not mandatory to use the decorator @pyqtSlot, but it is beneficial: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator

Comment: @eyllanesc yes, indeed so. I've made some more tests. Updating the answer

Comment: Never use time.sleep() in the main thread if you use Qt, it would be good if you remove: `time.sleep(0.15)`

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, I agree. Although it is mostly important when there's a GUI to hang. Updated the answer once more.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I found this relevant and fairly recent article: [Use PyQt's QThread to Prevent Freezing GUIs](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/#using-qthread-to-prevent-freezing-guis).

It is pretty much the minimal Python implementation of the approach given in [How To Really, Truly Use QThreads](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) and it provides a very clean example of how to use `QObject.moveToThread()`.

I copied the code and pasted it here for reference and discussion (I'm **not** the author):

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal
# Snip...

# Step 1: Create a worker class class Worker(QObject):
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        """Long-running task."""
        for i in range(5):
            sleep(1)
            self.progress.emit(i + 1)
        self.finished.emit()

class Window(QMainWindow):
    # Snip...
    def runLongTask(self):
        # Step 2: Create a QThread object
        self.thread = QThread()
        # Step 3: Create a worker object
        self.worker = Worker()
        # Step 4: Move worker to the thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        # Step 5: Connect signals and slots
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.reportProgress)
        # Step 6: Start the thread
        self.thread.start()
```

While the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324804/how-to-use-qthread-correctly-in-pyqt-with-movetothread/28628113#28628113) does work, I think the above approach is highly preferable, because

- it properly `quit`s the thread when the worker has finished,
- it performs clean-up for both the thread and the worker using `.deleteLater`, and
- it does not rely on the `pyqtSlot()` decorator to actually run in another thread (I tested this).

*Note:* In the above approach, the thread – and thus the worker, being connected to the `thread.started` signal – is started "manually", and the worker emits a `finished` signal when its work is done. However, in the accepted answer, the worker is started through a `start` signal, but there is no mechanism indicating whether its work is done.

Answer (score 0):

i was testing [Anthony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55866320/9371471) and noticed that cant get emitted value even with defining variable name in f1 or f2 methods.
it was giving "*TypeError: Worker.f1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'variable'*" error.it took 1 hour to notice that you need to determine type of emitted data to the slot. i'm just putting here reminder who is copy pasting the code and struggle with this..

```
import threading,sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QObject, QRunnable, QThread,
                          QThreadPool, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot)

class Worker(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
#        self.call_f1.connect(self.f1)
#        self.call_f2.connect(self.f2)

    call_f1 = pyqtSignal(object)<--- add type of data you want to get
    call_f2 = pyqtSignal()

    @pyqtSlot(object)  <--- add type of data you want to get
    def f1(self,variable):
        print('f1',variable, threading.get_ident()) <-- now you can get it
    
    @pyqtSlot()
    def f2(self):
        print('f2', threading.get_ident())

app = QCoreApplication([])
print('main', threading.get_ident())
my_thread = QThread()
my_thread.start()

my_worker = Worker()
my_worker.call_f1.connect(my_worker.f1)
my_worker.moveToThread(my_thread)
my_worker.call_f1.emit("test data") <--- Now you can add your data to emit 
my_worker.call_f2.connect(my_worker.f2)
my_worker.call_f1.emit()
my_worker.call_f2.emit()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```